# Why does the Myrish Crossbow have the Fast Quality?

Tags: song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

**Q: Why do some ranged weapons have these qualities if the text  about the "Divided Attack" indicates that it can only be made with the Fight Ability?**

The Myrish Crossbow (Table 9-3: Weapons; P 157) has the Fast Quality. The Light Crossbow has the Slow Quality.

> A Fast weapon is designed to slip past your opponent’s defenses and enable
>   its wielder to strike rapidly. When you make a divided attack using
>   a Fast weapon, you gain +1B on each test. Bonus Dice gained from the
>   Fast quality can exceed the normal limits.
>
> A Slow weapon is cumbersome and difficult to wield with speed and
>   grace. You may not make Divided Attacks using these weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the books, **the Myrish Crossbow is able to shoot three times before reloading**. The only way to reproduce this fast shooting currently in the rules would be to remove the slow quality that all crossbows naturally have.

However, from a balance standpoint, I believe that granting the fast quality was too much, you still have to reload it after three shots, and shouldnt be any quicker than any other crossbow to be honest. The developers probably thought this was some kind of repeating crossbow and that firing at multiple enemies at once would create fun gameplay experiences.

Comment: So can you use the divided attack with ranged weapons?

Comment: The way the special quality is worded, it doesn't make a distinction between melee or ranged weapons.